# CSS Navbar cut off by top of web page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav

Can someone  Help me identify why my bootstrap nav bar is being cut off from the top of my web page? I have been stuck in tutorial land for a while now and am really trying to start building websites but it has been tough so any advice is appreciated.

My CSS style is as follows:

```css
    #myVideo {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%; 
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      background-color: black;
      
    }
    
    body {
      font-size: 2rem;
      font-family: Tussilago;
    };
    
    
    nav{z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;}
    /* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */
    .content {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      color: #f1f1f1;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .container {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    button{color: black;}
    
    .navbar-header {
      background-color: #2c3e50;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Paluma Sound</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    
    
      </head>
      <body>
      
    
        <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
            </div>
        
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    
        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" class="center">
          <source src="Videos/asweareFINAL!!.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <!-- Optional: some overlay text to describe the video -->
        <script src="" async defer></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you share the HTML?

Comment: I updated the post! thank you

Comment: I created a stack-snippet for you.